# I cannot do a curl get call to my container in a centos server but i can do it in my linux local machine

Tags: curl, centos, docker-swarm

I have deployed a spring boot api in my ubuntu local machine through a swarm docker network and expose the port like 8080:8080. When I inspect the container where my spring boot api runs in linux i see the network configuration as follows:

[image]

And when I try to make a get call to one of the endpoints of the API i get the desired results:

```
curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/hello/
```

But when I deploy the same in my centos server i can see that the API runs well but when i do the same curl operation nothing happens.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe localhost resolves to an ipv6 address? Or there is no proxy exception for localhost? Try 127.0.0.1

Comment: it works with 127.0.0.1 thanks @pabloHenk